# Do I need to do 'git init' before doing 'git clone' on a project

Tags: git

I'm doing a `git clone` on a project following the instructions. But, do I need to do an `init` in the directory beforehand?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

`git clone` is basically a combination of:

- `git init` (create the local repository)
- `git remote add` (add the URL to that repository)
- `git fetch` (fetch all branches from that URL to your local repository)
- `git checkout` (create all the files of the main branch in your working tree)

Therefore, no, you don't have to do a `git init`, because it is already done by `git clone`.

Comment: You should also realise by now that if you DO a git-init, git-clone will abort with "fatal: destination path '...' already exists and is not an empty directory."

Comment: The remote that is added is called origin

Answer (score 15):

`git init` will create a new repository. When running `git clone`, what actually happens in the background is a `git init`, followed by `git remote add origin ${URL}` and then a `git pull`.

Typically, you only use `git init` if you already have code and you want to put it in a new Git repository.

In answer to your question: if you want to clone a project, then you do not need `git init`.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you would use `git init` if you had no code at all, but wanted to created a new repository. I usually do this when starting new projects, I initialize new repos, then start coding, and then commit files afterwards.