# git err :: Can't create remote/branch

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch, git-pull

I have problem to push to my github.
I've uploaded other projects on github.
but suddenly, problem appears.

In terminal, I run following:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/(username)/(reponame).git  
2. create remote to my github repogisry address.
3. git init  
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "message"
6. git push <repo> <branch>
```

but there's this message

```
"Cant's push refs to remote, Try running 'pull' to integrate your changes.
```

so I pull ->

```
git pull <remote name> <branch>
```

but there's other error :

```
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master
```

I checked out my folder.
In .git/refs there's no 'remotes' folder which has remote, branch.
but in VSCODE (when I run push to) there's  in popup I/'ve created.
To solve this error, deleted remote, create again, git init again, restart vscode,
but the error isn't fixed.

To test the other, I create other project, different github repo.
this project works.(in this project's folder the remotes folder is in refs)

but the project problems appeared before still has err.

how to solve this problem? Please help..

Comment: Try `git pull <repo> main`. The default branch on github is now main, not master

Comment: git pull <repo> main does not work too.
Other Projects :: git pull <repo> master work successfully, Only this project has error..

Comment: Why are you doing "2. create remote to my github repogisry address" and "3. `git init`" after cloning? Cloning creates a local repository (so there is no need to `git init`) with a remote already set (so there is no need to add a remote, unless you've cloned from a different remote).

Comment: And what is `<repo>` when you are doing `git pull`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I understand there's no need to create remote. but after I clone & commit -> start 'push to', there's a message 'there's no remote. add remote'  , so I create remote connected to my github repository. there may be another err ?

Comment: the `<repo>` when I'm doing `git pull` is  remote name I create, I wrote wrong name ( `<repo>` instead of `<remote name>` by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to clone a git-repo and then add a new branch remote are as follows:

1. `git clone https://server.name/git/testing.git`
2. `git checkout -b <branch-name> # create locally branch and checked out`
3. `git push <remote-name> <branch-name> # push local branch to remote`

So do not create a *new* git repo (`git init`) after clone, because `git clone` makes a `git init` in his workflow [Do I need to do 'git init' before doing 'git clone' on a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724921/do-i-need-to-do-git-init-before-doing-git-clone-on-a-project)

Look also at this [documentation](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-create-a-branch-in-remote-git-repository/)

Comment: Thank you for your help!!  I've fixed the problem :-)